# How should an ideal API documentation be?

Tags: api

I am creating so many APIs. We are planning to make it available publicly. There are so many APIs and it's responses. Each API can be called with more than one set of parameters and it may causing different result set according to calling parameters.

I don't have much idea how to document all this APIs with different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

While using a new api, I always check whose documentation is easy to understand.
I would suggest you, if possible try to create a video tutorial for your api (What is it? and How to use it?) Nothing can be better than a video which explains everything practically.

And for written documentation, please make sure that you are elaborating all the minute things that can affect from your api. Make sure to mention all the limitations of your api as well. Many times it happens that a developer forgets few things to mention and it takes many hours for an end user to figure out that limitation.

Good luck! Go ahead!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning about limitations. I really like that point. I can not find any examples for what i am looking for, i think  i will need to find a way myself. Thanks anyway.